# Incorrect results when using SSE intrinsics

Tags: c++, x86, sse, simd, intrinsics

I'm trying to every element of an array of 8 floats using SSE intrinsics, just to learn how to use them. However, when I attempt to write it like this:

```
alignas(16) float Numbers[8] = 
{0.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f, 7.0f};    

__m128 Group1 = _mm_load_ps(Numbers);
__m128 Group2 = _mm_load_ps(Numbers + 4*sizeof(float));
__m128 Zero = _mm_setzero_ps();

__m128 Sum1 = _mm_add_ps(Group1, Group2);     // Sum1 = Group1 + Group2
__m128 Sum2 = _mm_hadd_ps(Sum1, Zero);        // Sum2[31:0] = Sum1[31:0] + Sum1[63:32]
                                              // Sum2[63:32] = Sum1[95:64] + Sum1[127:96]
__m128 Sum3 = _mm_hadd_ps(Sum2, Zero);        // Sum3[31:0] = Sum2[31:0] + Sum2[63:32]

float Result;
_mm_store_ss(&Result, Sum3);
```

`Result` comes out to be 6, when it should be 28. I've been referring to a reference for these intrinsics, but I've had no avail to figuring out what is wrong with my logic here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing this line

```
__m128 Group2 = _mm_load_ps(Numbers + 4*sizeof(float));
```

to

```
__m128 Group2 = _mm_load_ps(Numbers + 4);
```

(Numbers is a float[], not a char[])

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I always want to think in byte offsets and forget that adding an integer to a pointer automatically takes the size of the type into account.

Answer (score 2):

@twin has already pointed out the main problem, but I thought I'd just add a couple of further points: (a) you don't need a zero vector and (b) you don't need separate sum vectors - you can do this all in-place, which should be more efficient. Here is the simplified code, which I've tested with gcc:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pmmintrin.h>

int main()
{
    float Numbers[8] __attribute__ ((aligned(16))) =
        {0.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f, 7.0f};

    __m128 Group1 = _mm_load_ps(Numbers);
    __m128 Group2 = _mm_load_ps(Numbers + 4);

    __m128 Sum = _mm_add_ps(Group1, Group2);
    Sum = _mm_hadd_ps(Sum, Sum);
    Sum = _mm_hadd_ps(Sum, Sum);

    float Result;
    _mm_store_ss(&Result, Sum);

    printf("Result = %g\n", Result);

    return 0;
}
```

Test it:

```
$ gcc -Wall -msse3 sum_ps.c && ./a.out
Result = 28
```

Comment: That's awesome. I see it takes a little bit of thinking outside of the box to get the most power out of SSE

Comment: Removing zero is good. But I doubt using Sum or Sum1, Sum2, etc changes anything to performance (readability is something else), for a built-in type like __m128 the first thing gcc will do is split Sum into Sum1, Sum2 and Sum3 (SSA_NAME if you want to read about it) ;-)

Comment: @MarcGlisse: yes, you're probably right - I didn't actually look at the generated code. I typically have to build with several different compilers so my instinct is to always make things as easy for the compiler as possible, but it may well make no difference in this instance.

Comment: @PaulR I timed this approach and the compiler's approach to adding 8 floats with -O3 and --ffast-math and the result is that they performed identically. The interesting thing is that the compiler actually generated one scalar move and 8 scalar adds. Funny how that's the same speed, but I guess it makes sense; there is going to be a dependency chain either way, so might as well take the instruction with the least latency

Comment: Modern CPUs have two or more scalar ALUs so you won't tend to see much benefit for a simple example like this. If you have more data, and more operations to perform on the data, then you may start to se 2x to 4x gain over scalar code.